# Оптимизация скорости обхода файлов

Tags: c#, алгоритм, .net, windows, winforms

Написал программу для сравнения имён файлов с шаблоном. Для этого прохожусь циклом foreach по Directory.EnumirateFiles, сравниваю имена файлов с шаблоном, и пути файлов с неверными именами записываю в Dictionary вместе с именем владельца. Далее также через foreach этот словарь записываю в DataTable и вывожу эту таблицу в DataGridView в WinForms.

Имена сравниваю с Regex шаблоном через if(Regex.IsMatch).

300_000 файлов сравнивается за 6:30 минут. Можно ли как-то ускорить этот процесс?

Я думал не проходить циклом по Directory.EnumirateFiles, а брать список путей файлов из PowerShell, или cmd или Total commander. Но в первом случае всё-таки быстрее получается. Так что ищу идеи как теоретически ускорить программу.

Comment: А зачем дважды проходить ```foreach```? Почему не записывать в ```DataTable``` одновременно с записью в ```Dictionary```?

Comment: Подключите логирование, пишите в лог на разных этапах и посмотрите таким образом - на что собственно время уходит, на какой этап. Также попробуйте поотключать какие-то фичи, например, для начала отключите всё, кроме обхода файлов - и посмотрите, сколько это займёт времени. Потом подключайте фичи по одной. Так и выясните - на что собственно тратится время. А потом уже можно будет начинать что-то оптимизировать - когда станет понятно, что именно тормозит.

Comment: Сравнить X имён и Y шаблонов - очевидное X*Y, узкое место и точка оптимизации. Так что думать, как брать файлы, нет смысла - ну выиграешь ты три секунды, и что, легче станет? Подумай, например, о перекрытии шаблонов (типа если шаблон А не подошёл, то шаблон Б тоже не подойдёт), или об иных путях оптимизации (вплоть до сортировки шаблонов по количеству шагов на их обработку, и самые быстрые вперёд).

Comment: Почему бы просто не показать код вместо того чтобы играть с воображением отвечающих? Воображаемый код оптимизировать невозможно.

Comment: Кстати, а имена файлов не могут повторяться? Ну, в разных каталогах - одинаковые имена. Если повторяются, то можно было бы закешировать результат сравнения и выиграть сколько-то времени. И сколько примерно файлов в одном каталоге? Винда очень плохо переваривает, когда счёт файлов в одном каталоге начинает идти на тысячи. По крайней мере раньше так было, не знаю как в современных версиях.

Comment: Для начала посмотрите, сколько времени будет работать `if(Regex.IsMatch)` с 300000 случайных строк, с занесением их в `Dictionary`.

Comment: Причин плохой производительности может быть много: плохой паттерн регулярки, приводящий к backtracking (возвратам); неоднократный проход одной и той же коллекции; частые коллизии в словаре... Короче, показывайте код.

Comment: [File globbing in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/file-globbing)

Answer (score 1):

Без исходного кода, сложно как то комментировать. Нашел пример: https://codernotes.ru/articles/c-c/poluchit-spisok-fajlov-i-papok-na-c.html
Первое что можно попробывать, это исходя их примера, уйти от регулярного выражения.
Получить сначало список файлов, а потом обрабатывать.
Посмотрите, где бутылочное горло? Предполагаю по кол-ву элементов - в цикле. Следовательно, уменьшайте "стоимость" цикла.
Для обработки полученного списка-перейти на многопоток.
Например, foreach, может такое:

```
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   Parallel.ForEach(str, s=> 
   {
   
   });
```

Где s- текущий объект, стр-собственно список файлов.
Избегайте конкатенацию строк - очень дорогое удовольствие.
Если не помогло, киньте хоть часть вашего кода, глянем.